# Ruby how to recall function until right condition?

Tags: ruby

I am figuring out how does Ruby return works, so I have a problem: I have a list and a function, that push different statements on it. And I need to figure out - how to recall function until user enter statement, that does not included on this list?

```
$my_list = []
def add_element()
  user_input = gets.to_i

  if $my_list.include?(user_input)
    puts 'There is already such number in list, re-enter your number. please.'
    return user_input
  else
    puts "Your number is - #{user_input}"
    $my_list.push(user_input)
  end
end
add_element
```

The Problem is that it can see if value already in list but I cannot figure out how to ask user to re-enter it again until he enter not duplicated number.

Comment: `loop do ... end`?

Comment: Damn, such question are always has the easiest answers and I always do not find out them. Thank you :)

Comment: A `while` block may make even more sense here

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Mark's idea,

```
$my_list = []
def add_element()
  user_input = gets.to_i
  while my_list.include?(user_input)
    puts 'There is already such number in list, re-enter your number. please.'
    user_input = gets.to_i
  end
  $my_list.push(user_input)
end
add_element
```

Should do the trick